# SQL Server - New to Triggers - INSERT data from a table into another table when inserted into 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

Let's say I have a db named Test, and I have two tables, PRODUCT & PALLETS.

I'm new to triggers and I want to create a trigger that will take a stored value in PALLETS, and insert it into PRODUCT when a new product is inserted, however X number of Products need the same Pallet number in the Product table.

Here is what I have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test.PALLETS ON Test.PARTS
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    declare @PalletID varchar(50);

    select @PalletID = PALLETS.PalletID from inserted PalletID;

    INSERT INTO PARTS(PalletID)
    VALUES(@PalletID)
```

---

The flow of information is as such.

1. Empty Pallet Barcode scanned and is inserted into PALLETS table from the front end
2. Products are scanned one at a time, the front end catches it and stores it in the PARTS table
3. Here is where I would like the PalletID to autofill 
   into the PRODUCT table with every Part record that is inserted up to X number of parts on a pallet
4. After that the front end will clear the pallet number and the process starts over

What I'm having trouble with is rather than coding this in the front end, I want to create a SQL Trigger that will autofill the PalletID field in every Product record that is created.

Suggestions? Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: That trigger, as it stands, assumes that only 1 row will be inserted at a time. It shouldn't; even if you're adamant it won't happen, treat your data as a dataset, not a single item. I'm not, however, really sure what your goal is here.

Comment: You are inserting to the same table you have a trigger? And since your aliasing your inserted table as PalletID, it would be PALLETID.PalletID

Comment: Do you want to take information from Pallet and put it into Product? That's what I understood from your question but it doesn't match the trigger at all

Comment: So, what I'm trying to do is insert the pallet ID into the product table, when a product is inserted. We are in a manufacturing environment, and the parts are individually scanned in to the application, and then stored in the database. While I understand this is not the optimal way to store data, I need the Trigger to autofill the Pallet ID from the Pallet table, into the parts table. 

If there is a better way to accomplish this or if I have misunderstood triggers in some way please come up with a better solution! I'm open to new ideas and I am pretty new at this

Comment: So when something is inserted into which table to you need to add something? It sounds from that like you don't need to add a trigger, you can just modify the insert into the Parts table to include information that should already be in the Pallets table? Can you edit the question to put the desired flow of information?

Comment: Alright, I updated the question with the information flow. Hopefully this gets us closer to a solution. Thanks for the interest in helping with this problem

Comment: So the pallet number is saved in it's own table? How is it cleared? Is it deleted from the table? How do you know when to clear it? Is it after a set number of products?

Comment: Yes, the pallet ID's are stored in a separate table. They are permanently stored. The front end will handle moving on to the next pallet. There are a set number of products that fit on each pallet to be shipped out

Comment: Ok... is the palletID field nullable in the Parts table?

Comment: Yes, if not it can be. This is still in development

Comment: If it's still in development I think you should look at modifying the actual insert statements - this doesn't seem like something that you should need a trigger for

Answer (score 0):

From what  I can gather abot your request, something like this might work:

```
Create Trigger Test.Pallets On Parts
    After Insert
As
Begin
    Declare @PalletID varchar(50)

    Select @PalletID = top 1 PalletId
    From Pallet Order by PalletID desc --Assuming your PalletID column is an auto-incrementing primary key, if that's wrong you'll need to change this statement

    Update Parts set PalletID = @PalletID
    Where PartID In ( --Replace PartID with your primary key if it's called something else
        Select PartID
        From Inserted
    )
End
```

No promises, as I'm not sure exactly what you want and don't have anything to test this on.

Also an issue with this is if someone tries to do a bulk insert of more products than you would want to allow for one pallet it won't know to switch to a new one.

Edit: The above should still work, but now that I know it's not the only option you should probably modify the original `insert` statement to have `Select top 1 PalletId From Pallet Order by PalletID desc` as a value for that column right off the bat.